# How to install certbot DNS plugin for DNS Made Easy?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, certbot

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and I want to get a wildcard certificate and my DNS provider is in the list - https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#dns-plugins
But when I try to do step [5. Install correct DNS plugin](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-other.html)

```
sudo apt-get install python3-certbot-dns-dnsmadeeasy
```

I always get

> Unable to locate package python3-certbot-dns-dnsmadeeasy

though I can see it on the [certbot github page](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/tree/master/certbot-dns-dnsmadeeasy) I can't get how to install this plugin to use with certbot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a direct answer to how to install the certbot dnsmadeeasy plugin but it worked for me so I went with this solution.
I used their Docker image - https://hub.docker.com/r/certbot/dns-dnsmadeeasy
It works the same as certbot with the dnsmadeeasy plugin installed so you can obtain a certificate by running:

```
docker run --rm -it --name certbot-dnsmadeeasy \
  -v {path_to_your_dnsmadeeasy.ini}:/dnsmadeeasy.ini \
  -v {path_to_where_you_want_to_store_certs}:/etc/letsencrypt \
  certbot/dns-dnsmadeeasy certonly \
  --dns-dnsmadeeasy \
  --dns-dnsmadeeasy-credentials /dnsmadeeasy.ini \
  -d {yourdomain}
```

You don't even need to have certbot installed on your machine.